# Jmeter - Not capturing the redirected URL

Tags: url, jmeter

I recorded a test in JMeter 2.11 with Ubuntu 12.04, which will redirect to different IP after logging in, The url specified in HTTP request default is for log in page, which will change based on the user after logging in.
I want to capture the redirected url after logging into a webpage.The URL specified in the HTTP request defaults is for initial log in , after that the IP address redirected to another.Please let me know if there is any method of capturing that redirected IP.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: have you checked redirect automatically checkbox in recording controller?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the screen shot below for ***HTTP sampler*** settings

[image: HTTP Sampler Settings]

Hope this will help